# Error in example code from the scikit-learn documentation for the Naive Bayes classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm a new Python user and have been running a Naive Bayes classifier model using the scikit-learn module. Is the following example code on the [scikit learn Naïve Bayes documentation page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html) correct?

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
gnb = GaussianNB()
y_pred = gnb.fit(iris.data, iris.target).predict(iris.data)
print("Number of mislabeled points out of a total %d points : %d"
```

Shouldn't the `gnb.fit()` function instead read:

```
y_pred = gnb.fit(iris.data.drop(columns=['target']), iris.target).predict(iris.data)
```

That is, the response variable needs to be manually removed from the predictor dataset. I was getting unreasonably high accuracy metrics for my model when a colleague pointed out that the code I had cribbed from the scikit-learn documentation page is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`iris.data` is not a dataframe, it's just a (150,4) numpy array with the 4 features.

`iris.target` is another numpy array with just the target class.

Not sure how you could call `drop` on the array (I just checked that I have an array and not a pd df, which makes sense, sklearn doesn't depend on pandas).

Comment: Great, thanks for checking - I understand the `drop` won't work. But even if the code syntax in the documentation is correct, it seems a little misleading, doesn't it? There's no indication in the code that the response variable has already been removed from the input dataset.

Comment: It has not. It is 4 features, not the target.

Comment: That would be helpful language to include in the documentation for users coming from other languages (like R) where you can specify models with shorthand like `y ~ ., data=analysis_dataset` and the algorithm knows to subtract y from the right hand side of the formula.